# no bluetooth devices found while scanning using flutter blue 0.8.0

Tags: flutter, dart, android-bluetooth

i'm new in coding in dart with flutter and i'm using flutter blue 0.8.0 to scan for bluetooth devices and connect with them but when while scanning it shows in my terminal while I'm sure that there are bluetooth devices near :

```
I/flutter (15384): Devices: \[\]

I/flutter (15384): Devices: \[\]

I/flutter (15384): Devices: \[\]

I/BluetoothAdapter(15384): STATE_ON

I/BluetoothAdapter(15384): STATE_ON

I/BluetoothAdapter(15384): STATE_ON

I/BluetoothAdapter(15384): STATE_ON

D/BluetoothLeScanner(15384): Start Scan with callback

D/BluetoothLeScanner(15384): onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=10 mScannerId=0

I/BluetoothAdapter(15384): STATE_ON

I/BluetoothAdapter(15384): STATE_ON

D/BluetoothLeScanner(15384): Stop Scan with callback
```

**This is in androidmanifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

and this is my code in main.dart :

```
class BluetoothScanPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BluetoothScanPageState createState() => _BluetoothScanPageState();
}

class _BluetoothScanPageState extends State<BluetoothScanPage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  FlutterBlue flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance;
  List<BluetoothDevice> devices = [];
  bool isScanning = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initBluetooth();
  }

  void _initBluetooth() async {
    await _enableBluetooth();
    await _requestBluetoothPermission();
    _startScanning();
  }

  Future<void> _enableBluetooth() async {
    if (!await flutterBlue.isOn) {
      print('Requesting Bluetooth enable...');
      await FlutterBlue.instance.startScan();
      await FlutterBlue.instance.stopScan();
    }
  }

  Future<void> _requestBluetoothPermission() async {
    var status = await Permission.bluetooth.request();
    if (status.isDenied) {
      print('Bluetooth permission is required to use this feature.');
    }
  }

  void _startScanning() {
    setState(() {
      isScanning = true;
    });

    try {
      flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4));
      flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            devices = results.map((result) => result.device).toList();
            print('Devices: $devices');
          });
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error starting scan: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    flutterBlue.stopScan();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Bluetooth Scan'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          if (isScanning)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          else
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: devices.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(devices[index].name),
                    subtitle: Text(devices[index].id.toString()),
                    onTap: () {
                      _connectToDevice(context, devices[index]);
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _connectToDevice(BuildContext context, BluetoothDevice device) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => DeviceDetailsPage(device: device),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DeviceDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final BluetoothDevice device;

  DeviceDetailsPage({required this.device});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Device Details'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Details for ${device.name}'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class YourNewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<BluetoothDevice> devices;

  YourNewPage({required this.devices});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Found Devices'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: devices.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(devices[index].name),
            subtitle: Text(devices[index].id.toString()),
            onTap: () {
              _connectToDevice(context, devices[index]);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _connectToDevice(BuildContext context, BluetoothDevice device) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => DeviceDetailsPage(device: device),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class BluetoothDeviceList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BluetoothDeviceListState createState() => _BluetoothDeviceListState();
}

class _BluetoothDeviceListState extends State<BluetoothDeviceList> {
  FlutterBlue flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance;
  List<BluetoothDevice> devices = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startScanning();
  }

  void startScanning() {
    flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4));

    flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          devices = results.map((result) => result.device).toList();
          print('Devices: $devices');
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    flutterBlue.stopScan();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: devices.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(devices[index].name),
          subtitle: Text(devices[index].id.toString()),
          onTap: () {
            _connectToDevice(context, devices[index]);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _connectToDevice(BuildContext context, BluetoothDevice device) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => DeviceDetailsPage(device: device),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you stopping the scanning right after starting the scanning?

Comment: @tomerpacific it stops automatically after 2 minutes due to this line :      flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 120));
but in the app page it keeps reloading without showing any devices